# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug' when importing a jar

Tags: java, android, jdbc, jar

I added [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzbtqYARQ9TpUVhySkpOUVFQNUE) jar file in my android studio project but when I tried to compile the project I am getting the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

To import this jar I just Right Clicked on app -> New Module -> Import Jar Package.

And added this module to the dependency using File -> Project Structure -> Select the Module -> click on + and select Module Dependency

Here is my dependency in gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':com.cevious.tally.jdbc')  }
```

**Output**:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at    com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.256 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My JDK version is 1.8 and my Compile SDK version is 15. I dont think this is caused by JDK because this works fine on Netbeans with the same JDK version.

This Jar file contains some JDBC code. I doubt that this may be the problem.

Please help me to compile this jar in my project.